# Prove that if $n$ is an odd integer, there is an integer $m$ such that $n = 8m + 1$ or $n = 8m + 3$ or $n = 8m +5$ or $n = 8m + 7$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that if $n$ is an odd integer, there is an integer $m$ such that $n = 8m + 1$ or $n = 8m + 3$ or $n = 8m +5$ or $n = 8m + 7$

So,

n = 4k + 1. If k is even, there exists an integer m such that k = 2m, so n = 4(2m) + 1 = 8m + 1. but, if k is odd, there exists an integer m such that k = 2m + 1, so n = 4(2m + 1) + 1 = 8m + 5. So this makes it true

n = 4k + 3. If k is even, there exists an integer m such that k = 2m, so n = 4(2m) + 3 = 8m + 3. But, if k is odd, there exists an integer m such that k = 2m + 1, so n = 4(2m + 1) + 3 = 8m + 7. This also makes it true.

Not sure if this is correct or not...

Comment: What if anything have you tried? MSE is not a homework machine.

Comment: My whole problem is that I don't know where to start with this problem. I am not looking for an answer. I'm looking for hints as posted below, on how to go about solving it.

Comment: n = 4k + 1. If k is even, there exists an integer m such that k = 2m, so n = 4(2m) + 1 = 8m + 1. but, if k is odd, there exists an integer m such that k = 2m + 1, so n = 4(2m + 1) + 1 = 8m + 5. So this makes it true?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, every number can be written as

$n=ak$ or

$n=ak+1$ or

$n=ak+2$ or

... or

$n=ak+(a-1)$

For example, if a=2 then it's either

$n=2k$ or $n=2k+1$

The second case is the odd numbers.

Using similar approach, how can you write $k$, in order to get your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that any odd integer must satisfy $m\equiv 1,3,5,7\mod 8$.

This is rather straight-forward, and is equivalent to what you want.

Comment: I think this is just a rephrasing of OP's question.

Comment: It is, to a large degree.  I'm hoping that the OP will see this and it will somehow jog his problem solving skills.

Comment: I also couldn't think of anything else hint-wise that wasn't simply the answer. XD

Comment: Sometimes, all someone needs is a reformulation of the question in a more palatable form. I like this hint. +1